# Various PHP questions

Tags: php, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes

1. about this function:

   ```
   function requireSSL() {     

       if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
           header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
           header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
           exit;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

   SSL requires port 443, so in this piece of code if not 443 then forced to use https?  and if 443 it would automatically use https I assumed. What's the moved permanently used for?
2. The code `header("Location: .");`

   What's use of the above, it's nothing more than telling it to stay at the same page. By default it should stay at the same page, isn't it redundant?

Comment: FWIW, you probably should have asked two separate questions for this, since they're completely different. You'd get more specific + better answers for each.

Comment: And neither of these questions are about PHP. They're about the HTTP(S) protocol and its uses

Answer (score 2):

> SSL requires port 443

Not always. That is the *default* port. HTTPS can be configured to run on other ports. A better way to check is:

```
if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {

}
```

> What's the moved permanently used for?

From [w3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any
>   future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned
>   URIs

In other words, a browser should *remember* that the requested URI is moved and request the new URI anytime the user requests that old URI again.

> By default it should stay at the same page, isn't it redundant?

That's not what the code is doing. It's redirecting to the https version when the user requests the non-https version.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is redirecting the client to use `https` in case it does not use `https`. `301` tells the client to always use the new location.

The redirection is done via the `Location` header, and you are only partly right, the page is the same, but the connection is done via `https` and not `http`. If the client is already connected via `https`, the redirect does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

1) HTTP/1.1 301 is for letting the browser and search engines know that the page has moved to https://example.com/thepage.php

2) This code is used for specific pages or sites that require SSL. Example: Shopping carts, banks, logins

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS goes through port 443 by default. This code redirects the user, using the Location-header, to the HTTPS if the user is visiting through plain HTTP.

The 301 instructs the browser to always redirecting HTTP to HTTPS on succeeding requests on that URL.

In psuedo-code it does this:

```
if (user is NOT visiting through HTTPS)
  redirect permanently to the same URL, but then through HTTPS
```

So no, it's not redundant, for if anyone visits that page using HTTPS, the body of the if-block will not be executed and no redirect takes place.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the function does what you think.

Let's go through each of those you want to learn more about:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

This sets the HTTP response status code. Code: `301`. Message: `Moved Permanently`. `301` is a permanent redirect, this just tells the browser (HTTP client), next time to use the new address directly instead of the requested one.

The new address is given with a `Location:` header.

```
header("Location: .");
```

This code is just plain wrong code. Don't expect that it works. I assume somebody wanted to redirect to the same page again, but this does not work this way. A `Location:` needs to be followed by an absolute URL, this is a relative URL and won't work. Absolute URLs always start with `http://` or `https://` and contain a host-name.